# Grails: Session and Transactions not working properly (fails or detach after single flush)

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am using grails 2.4.0 and trying to bulk upload data through csv file, i am using withNewSession for this work and using this session to upload the data in database. while i call a save function it flushes automatically and thats it,only single record is saved and the program dont run after it. i've tried different methods like cleanupgorm(), withTransactions, withSession but all methods are slow and flush is not happening manually. What i want is to flush manually after 1000 records or 100 records so the process becomes faster. Also one thing more, i've worked on both Grails 3.3.4 and Grails 2.4.0 and  "def SessionFactory" is not injecting there. i am unable to understand this

### Here is my code:

```
Caller.withNewSession { session ->
          def count = 0
          Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()
          try {
             groovyFile.eachLine {

             def callCallerList = [:]                    
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new 
             SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
             Date resultdate = new 
             Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
             String[] tagData = it.split(',')
             if (tagData.length != 0) {
                 def caller
                 //Saving caller
                 try {
                   caller = new                     
                   Caller(callingNumber:tagData.getAt(0), callerName: 
tagData.getAt(1))


                   if (caller.validate()) {
                      if (session.save(caller)) {
                             cout = 1
                             println(count)
                          }

                     } else {

    caller.errors.allErrors.each {
                        println it
                                  }
                                }
                     } catch (Exception ex) {
                          log.error(ex.getMessage())
                     }
                    //Call Caller List
    switch (tagData.length) {
       case 1:
       callCallerList = createCallCallerList(null, null, caller, 
callerList)
       break 

       case 2:
       callCallerList = createCallCallerList(null, null, caller, 
callerList)
       break

       case 3:
      callCallerList = createCallCallerList(tagData.getAt(2), null, 
caller, callerList)
       break

      case 4:
      callCallerList = createCallCallerList(tagData.getAt(2), 
tagData.getAt(3), caller, callerList)
      break
      }
 }
 if (!tagData.getAt(0)) {
    log.error "Error in contact validator and error is "
    invalidBuilder.append("*** " + sdf.format(resultdate) + "*** " +
                                           tagData + "\n\r")
    invalidBuilder.append("Calling number not provided. It is a 
mandatory field." + "\n\r")
    invalidContactsCount++
    callCallerList.message = "OK"
   }
   if (callCallerList.message != "OK") {
   log.error "Error in contact 
   validator and error is "
   invalidBuilder.append("*** " + 
   sdf.format(resultdate) + "*** " +
   tagData + "\n\r")

   invalidBuilder.append(callCallerList?.message + "\n\r")
   invalidContactsCount++

   count++

   if(count.mod(200) == 0)
   {
     session.flush()
     session.clear()
   }

  }

  tx.commit()
  session.clear()
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
  // println ex.getMessage()
 log.error("Exception while reading the file 
                        and exception is ", ex)

  }
}
```